# RoR rails, f.select onchange of value, making portions of html visible

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-5

I am fairly new to Rails. 
I was able to correctly get the onclick to function for a f.checkbox.

Now I am trying to do something similar for a f.select in a _form.

here is my working code for a checkbox
erb portion :

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :air? %>
      <%= f.check_box :air, :id => "chk_air", :onclick => "manageAirDisp();" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% if request.air? %>
    <div class="col-md-4", id="MultiButton", style="display: block">
  <% else %>
    <div class="col-md-4", id="MultiButton", style="display: none">
  <% end %>
      <button onclick="showAirMulti(); return false;", class="btn-custom-normal">Show/Hide Multi-Destinations</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

on top of the _frm the corresponding script portion:

```
function manageAirDisp (){
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('chk_air');
  // this check below checks if checkbox is checked or not.
  if (checkbox.checked){
    document.getElementById("air_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("MultiButton").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("air_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("MultiButton").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Now what I cannot get to work with a dorp down selection instead:
the erb portion:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :event %>
      <!-- < f.check_box :event, :id => "chk_event", :onclick => "manageEvent();" > -->
      <%= f.select :event, [['Unkown', 'unk'], ['yes', 'yes'], ['no', 'no']], :onchange => "manageEvent();" } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row",  id="event_blk", style="display: none">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :registration, "addQuestion?" %>
      <%= f.check_box :addquestion %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and now the corresponding script portion that I canot get to work:

```
function manageEvent(){
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('chk_event');
  // this check below checks if checkbox is checked or not.
  if (selection.val() = "yes"){
    document.getElementById("event_blk").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("event_blk").style.display = "none";
  }
   // to check on value instead it should look as follows:
  // if (checkbox.val() = "something") {  then do something }

}
```

So what I want to do is to have the section event_blk to become visible when the user select "yes" and that as soon as they have it selected, or make it invisible as soon as they select no or unk

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't declaring `selection` -- you are setting the variable `checkbox` instead.

Also, you should use `.value` instead of `.val()`.

Try this:

```
function manageEvent(){

    // change checkbox to selection
    var selection = document.getElementById('chk_event');

    // changed selection.val() to selection.value
    if (selection.value == "yes"){
        document.getElementById("event_blk").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("event_blk").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You will also need to fix your `select` helper. If you check out the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), you will find that the last two arguments accepted by the `select` helper are the `options` hash and the `html_options` hash. You need to pass `:onchange` in the `html_options` hash. Also, Rails will default to `[model_name]_[attribute_name]` as the `id` for the `select` element, so you will also need to pass `:id => "chk_event"` in the `html_options` hash if you want to use that string as the `id`:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :event %>
      <!-- < f.check_box :event, :id => "chk_event", :onclick => "manageEvent();" > -->
      <%= f.select :event, 
                   [['Unkown', 'unk'], ['yes', 'yes'], ['no', 'no']],
                   {}, #empty options hash
                   { :id => "chk_event", :onchange => "manageEvent();" } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you chester, I updated the code to reflect your code, it does not throw any errors, but also does not work... could it be that the 'onchange' call itself does not work?  is there a way I can test that out?  or debug it in a way.

Comment: @JLE, I updated the answer - I missed a few thing in your erb file. I don't think the `onchange` function was firing before because it was not passed to the `select` helper correctly. Take a look at the actual html rendered and I'll bet that `onchange="manageEvent();"` was not present in your `select` element.

Comment: As far as debugging, you could throw a `console.log()` into your function to print out a variable a run-time. Or better yet,  try using the developer tools in Chrome, or whatever browser you are using, to add breakpoints to you code in order to see whats going on during execution (or to see if your code is being executed at all).